# XCode: Why is a NSLayoutConstraint being added to my code?

Tags: xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I have this xib:

[image]

and I have these constraints:

[image]

all the constraints on the superview have a constant of 0 and a multiplier of 1. When I run my app, I get this complain in the log:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800028a7d0 UIView:0x7fcde1628e60.leading == UIButton:0x7fcde1629400.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800028a8c0 UIView:0x7fcde1629040.leading == UIView:0x7fcde1628e60.leading + 50>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800028a910 UIView:0x7fcde1629040.leading == UIButton:0x7fcde1629400.trailing>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800028a910 UIView:0x7fcde1629040.leading == UIButton:0x7fcde1629400.trailing>
```

The second one, that has the leading of the view set to the leading of the superview + 50. I never made that constraint. Is XCode adding it? Also, why is it duplicating the leading = button trailing constraint?